# Differential/derivative of left translation for (matrix) Lie groups

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups

I am very new to Lie groups and manifolds. In my self study, many times I have come across "differential (or derivative) of the left translation" (for example, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group%E2%80%93Lie_algebra_correspondence#The_Lie_algebra_of_a_Lie_group)). I don't fully understand what is meant by differential/derivative here. I would appreciate any attempt to explain this concept both formally and intuitively.

For example, what does the differential/derivative here mean and how is it defined? Does the definition require charts in general (I have seen how smooth maps are defined between two manifolds)? Would it have a more convenient form in the special case of matrix Lie groups? What does it do?

Part of the answer given to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1199877/what-is-the-differential-of-left-translation) is definitely relevant. But I am not sure where does $$dL_{g}(v) = \frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0} L_{g}\exp(tv)$$ come from? (I know that $\exp(tv)$ is a curve on $G$ that passes through the identity element at $t=0$ and $v$ is its tangent vector at the identity). Is this the definition of differential of $L_{g}$? Is there a backstory?

---

To make this question more concrete, let me set up a standard notation. Let $G$ be a matrix Lie group. $L_g : G \to G$ for any $g \in G$ maps an element of $G \ni p$ to $ L_g(p) := g p$. Then, the differential of $L_g$, denoted by $dL_g$ is a mapping from a tangent space at any $p \in G$ to the tangent space at $L_g(p)$.

Comment: $dL_g$ is the pushforward of the map $L_g$. How is that defined?

Comment: Just to be clear, you are familiar with treating $dL_g$ as a map between tangent spaces, but you want clarification on how it can be written in terms of the exponential map? The formula you give only gives an expression for $dL_g$ as a map from $T_eG$ to $T_gG$.

Comment: Technically, tangent vectors are derivations. In this sense, the above definition is incomplete.

Comment: Thanks for the help folks. @Kajelad I wasn't familiar with pushforward - it makes sense. To make this complete, do I need to mention a point on $G$ (say, $p$) at which $d L_g$ is being calculated? In that first I need the curve that goes through $p$ at $t = 0$ and has a tangent vector $v$. In this case, $p \exp(t p^{-1} v)$ would be such a curve. Mapping this curve via $L_g$ gives $g p \exp(t p^{-1} v)$. The tangent vector at $ t = 0 $ is then going to be $ g v$. And this holds for any $p$. Is this correct?

Comment: @OliverJones Thanks for the help! I haven't fully studied the alternative definition of tangent vectors as derivatives. Are these two definitions equivalent and equally "formal"? Perhaps related to this question: what is allowing me here to take the "usual" derivative $ \frac{d}{d t} $ from a curve such as $t \mapsto \exp(t v) \in G$ without involving charts? I guess this has something to do with the fact that $ G $ is assumed to be a matrix Lie group - can you please elaborate? Thanks!

Comment: @newbie777 I believe that the above result is given for any Lie group but it's not entirely accurate. Viewing tangent vectors as derivations, which you have to do for abstract manifolds, the result should read $dL_g(v)(f) = \frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0}f(L_g\exp(tv))$, where $f$ is any map  $f:G\rightarrow \Bbb{R}$.

Comment: @OliverJones Understood, thanks. Also, can you please help me to understand why/if we are allowed to take the "usual" derivative in the case of matrix Lie groups (as opposed to abstract manifolds)?

Comment: @newbie777 In the case of matrix Lie groups, the calculations simplify a lot. Left translation corresponds to matrix multiplication, the tangent space to $G$ at the identity is a Lie algebra of matrices and the exponential is the matrix exponential. I think that in this case $dL_g: T_eG\rightarrow T_gG$ corresponds to matrix multiplication as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you note, $dL_g:T_hG\to T_{gh}G$ (or the differential of any smooth map) is already a well-defined linear a map between tangent spaces without further reference to the group structure. In terms of velocities of curves, it is defined by:
$$
dL_g\left(\left.\frac{d}{dt}\gamma(t)\right|_{t=t_0}\right)=\left.\frac{d}{dt}\left(L_g(\gamma(t))\right)\right|_{t=t_0}
$$
Equivalently, in terms of derivations:
$$
[dL_g(V_h)](f)=V_h(f\circ L_g)
$$
These two definitions of tangent vectors are equivalent: we may equate every velocity with a derivation given by
$$
\left(\left.\frac{d}{dt}\gamma(t)\right|_{t=t_0}\right)(f)=\left.\frac{d}{dt}\left(f(\gamma(t))\right)\right|_{t=t_0}
$$
If this isn't already familiar, it might be worth checking that the above definitions of the differential agree.

Understanding its relationship with the exponential map will require establishing a few facts about the Lie algebras and the exponential map.

The Lie algebra $\text{Lie}(G)$, can be identified with two vector spaces:

- The tangent space $T_eG$
- The space of left-invarant vector fields on $G$

To go from the first to the second, we can just evaluate the vector field at $e$. To go from a tangent vector $v\in T_e M$ to a vector field $V$, we let $V_e=v$, and the value of $V$ at any other point $g$ must be $V_g=dL_gv$ by left invariance. Because of this, we often use the same symbol to refer to both a tangent vectors at $e$ and the corresponding left-invariant vector field. Instead, I'll treat elements $V\in\text{Lie}(G)$ as left-invariant vector fields and use subscripts $V_e\in T_eM$ to refer to their values at particular points.

The exponential map $\exp:\text{Lie}(G)\to G$ is given by
$$
\exp(V)=\gamma_V(1)
$$
Where $\gamma_V$ is the unique integral curve of the left-invariant vector field $V$ satisfying $\gamma_V(0)=e$ and $\frac{d}{dt}\gamma(t)=V_{\gamma(t)}$ (often called the *one parameter subgroup generated by* $V$). A consequence of this is that $\gamma_V(t)=\exp(tV)$.

Let $U_e\in T_e G$, and $U$ be the corresponding left-invariant vector field. We can use definition of the differential, and the fact that $\left.\frac{d}{dt}\exp(tU)\right|_{t=0}=U_e$ to arrive at the formula you give:
$$
\left.\frac{d}{dt}\left[L_g\exp(tU)\right]\right|_{t=0}=dL_g\left.\frac{d}{dt}\exp(tU)\right|_{t=0}=dL_gU_e
$$
We see, somewhat more explicitly, this is only an expression for how $dL_g$ acts on tangent vectors at the identity.

Comment: Thanks @Kajelad - and can you please help me to understand why are we allowed to talk about $\frac{d}{dt}$ of a curve that lives on the matrix Lie group? (as far as I know, $\frac{d}{dt}$ would be meaningless for curves on abstract manifolds - I'm trying to understand *formally* what property of matrix Lie groups allows us to do this? is it the fact that they are embedded in a Euclidean space? can we do the same thing for sphere?)

Comment: The velocity of a curve $\frac{d}{dt}\gamma$ is a tangent vector; there are several definitions which work on arbitrary manifolds. The most common one is that tangent vectors are *(pointwise) derivations* (i.e. pointwise directional derivatives): maps from smooth real-valued functions to real numbers satisfying $$v_p(fg)=f(p)v_p(g)+g(p)v_p(f)$$ where $f,g$ are smooth real valued functions, $p$ is a point on the manifold, and $v_p$ is a derivation at $p$. We can think of the velocity of a curve at a point as a derivation, as in the answer.

Comment: Thanks again @Kajelad. I understand there is a more general/formal definition of tangent vectors as a derivation; i.e., in general $\frac{d}{dt} \gamma(t)$ is not even meaningful according to the definition of $\frac{d}{dt}$. But in the case of matrix Lie groups it seems that we can pretend $\gamma(t)$ maps to $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ and simply take the usual derivative? i.e., if $\gamma(t)  \in \mathrm{SO}_n$ is a $n \times n$ matrix-valued function, I can easily compute tangent vectors to $\gamma(t)$ by explicitly computing the usual derivative of the $n \times n$ matrix-valued function wrt $t$.

Comment: Yes. What you're effectively doing there is using the matrix elements as a set of global coordinates, with the corresponding partial derivatives as a bases for the tangent spaces. The matrix valued function $\frac{d}{dt}\gamma(t)$ is the coordinate form of the abstract tangent vector $\frac{d}{dt}\gamma$, where each element of the matrix is the component in the corresponding partial derivative.