# Charts for matrix Lie groups

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

I have several basic questions about matrix Lie groups.
Suppose $G$ is a matrix Lie group, say $\mathrm{GL}(n)$ or $\mathrm{SO}(n)$.

1. I understand that elements of $G$ can be looked at points in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$. Does this make the study of these matrix Lie groups easier in any sense? Please elaborate.
2. What are "natural" choices for charts on such matrix Lie groups (particularly, $\mathrm{GL}(n)$ and $\mathrm{SO}(n)$). Can you provide an example atlases for these two specific matrix Lie groups?
3. Is it possible to define valid charts based on the tangent space and exponential/logarithm maps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) It is just the observation that an $n \times n$ matrix has $n^2$ entries, and so you can think of it as a vector in $n^2$-dimensional space. Going along with question #2, this can help find coordinates.

(2) Going along with point (1) above, for $\mathrm{GL}_n$, you can take the $n^2$ matrix entries as a set of global coordinates, since $\mathrm{GL}_n$ is an open subset of $\Bbb{R}^{n^2}$.

(3) Near the identity element of $G$, the exponential map is a diffeomorphism, so yes, the tangent space can be used to get local coordinates.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry if my questions are dumb/obvious :)

(2) Formally, does this imply $\phi : g \to \mathrm{vec}(g)$ is a chart for any matrix Lie group $G \ni g$? If so (probably not), then we can cover the entire manifold $G$ with a single chart? I guess this only holds for $\mathrm{GL}_n$ and not $\mathrm{SO}_n$ (which we know doesn't have dimension $n^2$). In that case, is there a special way to create charts for matrix Lie groups that works also for e.g. $\mathrm{SO}_n$.

(3) This holds for any matrix Lie group? "Near identity" means such a chart doesn't cover the entire manifold?

Comment: (3) ... I was asking this question because charts are supposed to map open subsets of a $d$-dimensional manifold to open sets in $\mathbb{R}^d$. But tangent spaces (at any point) already provide a $d$-dimensional vector space (isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^d$ - correct?). I was wondering if in general (and especially for matrix Lie groups) this can be leveraged to construct an Atlas? (e.g., by defining chart maps similar to exp/log maps at any point).

Comment: can you please see the above questions? Thanks!

Comment: (2) No, $g \to \mathrm{vec}(g)$ is not a global chart all the time. Just for $\mathrm{GL}_n$. (3) "Near identity" means an open set containing the identity. Maybe not the entire manifold. The exponential map may just identify an open set of the tangent space (containing the zero vector) with an open set of the group containing the identity.

Comment: Thanks @Nick. (2) Understood. I was asking this because of another question I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3375125/differential-derivative-of-left-translation-for-matrix-lie-groups#comment6958602_3378608): what structure allows us to talk about $\frac{d}{dt} \gamma(t)$ for curves that live on a matrix Lie group (not necessarily $\mathrm{GL}_n$) where $\frac{d}{dt}$ is the derivative in the usual sense? According to you, this is not because $\mathrm{vec}$ is a chart (which makes sense) - but still this puzzles me - e.g., can we do this for curves on the sphere?

Comment: You can talk about $\frac{d}{dt} \, \gamma(t)$ for curves on any manifold. It is just the tangent vector of the curve.

Comment: (3) Understood. Is it clear what the boundaries of this open set are, e.g., for $\mathrm{SO}_n$? And what about other parts of the matrix Lie group? Can we cover a neighborhood of every point using its tangent space and maps (charts) similar to the exponential/logarithm maps? (maybe shifted by the point?) Thanks again!

Comment: but $\frac{d}{dt}$ (in the usual sense) requires subtracting the curve at two points which is meaningless in general, correct?

Comment: Ok, maybe not in "the usual sense", if by that you mean the derivative in $\Bbb{R}^n$. I mean in the abstract sense: it is a vector in the abstract tangent space.

Comment: But suppose I have an expression for $\gamma(t)$ (a matrix-valued function of $t$ that lives on the *matrix Lie group*). I have seen papers that take the "usual" derivative to find tangent vectors. Is this allowed? (does it result in a tangent vector at $\gamma(0)$ if we evaluate the derivative at $t = 0$?)

Alternatively, one may possibly define this as derivative through charts - i.e., $\frac{d}{dt} \phi(\gamma(t))$ for some chart $\phi$ that covers $\gamma(0)$. Is this how you think of $\frac{d}{dt} \gamma(t)$? (which is why I originally asked if $\mathrm{vec}$ is a chart ...)

Comment: Since "matrix" Lie groups are subgroups of $\mathrm{GL}_n$, they are closed subsets in $\Bbb{R}^{n^2}$, and so yes, you can take the "usual" derivative. You can view it as a vector in $\Bbb{R}^{n^2}$, which is tangent to the submanifold (the group).

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for a statement like this. Can you please elaborate on this? is the fact they are **closed** subsets of Euclidean space allows this? If so, why exactly? Is this, e.g., allowed on sphere? (as a non-matrix Lie group)

Comment: This comments section is getting a bit long. You should probably post another, more specific, question. I'd be happy to talk more, but I don't want to turn the comments into a message board.